# When screen rotated of device then audio player play and pause button not work

Tags: android

In android audio app, when the screen of the device rotates then audio play and pause button do not work. I'm using a seek bar for track the audio duration which also is not working.

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);

public void playAudio(View view){

        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseAudio(View view){
        mPlayer.pause();
    }
```

Comment: are you using a fragment

Comment: Please post your whole code instead.

Comment: I am using activity